# How to check json Responce in Android?

Tags: android, json

I'm getting the JSON response as {"Sync-string" [{"Sync-check[{"Response":"N"}]}]}.

Right now I want to check the response is "Y" or "N".How can I check the response is n or y .Can someone help me here.Any help is appreciable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: micky : Actually I want to check this json object  Response":"N" = is "Y" or "N" in if condition how can i do this.

Comment: @JAndroid: `{"Sync-string" [{"Sync-check[{"Response":"N"}]}]}` is not a valid json String

Comment: @micky : Thats why i want to check if N then alert if y then go to database

Answer (score 0):

Go through [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) to know about json structure and how can parse json in Android App. Check with this link and if you any query post it!

**Update**

First know the structure of the json. Json node starts with "[" represents the array and "{" represents Json Object. In your response,

```
 {"Sync-string" : [{"Sync-check[{"Response":"N"}]}]}
```

Get the Json Object named "Sync-string" like,

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("ur json string");
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Sync-string");//getting the array
```

Now loop through your JSON Array like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);//get first object in array
                     JSONArray innerarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Sync-check");//sync-check array
  for (int i = 0; i < innerarray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject c = innerarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("Response");
}
}
```

Try this, but not verified code

Comment: Suppose here is my new json string = {"Sync-string" [{"Sync-check[{"Response":"y"} , "dgrer","ertetye3"]}]} then how to parse it

Comment: First let us know what u hav tried so far? Then only we can help you...Seems you not yet tried anything

Comment: I'm trying to check if {"Sync-string" [{"Sync-check[{"Response":"y"} , "dgrer","ertetye3"]}]}  then data is there and save into local db .If {"Sync-string" [{"Sync-check[{"Response":"N"}]}]} then alert msg